# JS PreLoading Images Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created an array with the URLs of all the images on my page, I then send this array to a function which in turn loads each one up. The page then loads the layout. I am however receiving the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

Any help much appreciated

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    preLoadImages();
    useIsotope();
});

function useIsotope() {
    var $container = $('#work').isotope({
        filter: "*"
    });

    $('#control ul li a').click(function () {
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
        return false;
    });
}

function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function () {
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}

function preLoadImages() {
    var imageArray = new Array();
    $('.imgWrapper a img').each(function (index) {
        imageArray.push(this.src)
    });
    console.log(imageArray)
    preLoad(imageArray) // HERE IS THE ERROR
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `preload(imageArray)` instead of `preLoad(imageArray)`.

JavaScript is case sensitive. ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Case_sensitivity))

Answer (score 0):

I can't see an error with where you have commented, but this looks like an error.

You are setting 
      $container = $('#work').isotope({
        filter: "*"
      });

then trying to call

```
$container.isotope({ filter: selector });
```

I think you might want to write it this way.

```
function useIsotope(){

  var $container = $('#work');
  $container.isotope({ filter: "*" });

  $('#control ul li a').click(function(){

    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
    return false;
  });

}
```

**Update** after reading @Guy's answer, I too see the preload v. preLoad error.